# Create a file upload with CakePHP and security Hash

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-4.x

I have a PageController allowing to add, edit and delete pages. For each page, we can upload one single image that I will be using as banner. I am using the Cake Security Hash to change filenames but I am not sure if I am using it properly. Some pages may have the same image so, using my code below, deleting or updating a page will remove the images for all the other pages having the same image...

Can you please check if my code below does make sense or is there any way to improve it ?

```
public function add()
{
    $page = $this->Pages->newEmptyEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $page = $this->Pages->patchEntity($page, $this->request->getData());

        if(!$page->getErrors()) {
            $image = $this->request->getData('image_file');
            $filename = $image->getClientFilename();
            $filename = \Cake\Utility\Security::hash($image->getClientFilename(), 'sha1');

            $image->moveTo(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'pages' . DS . $filename);
            $page->image = $filename;
        }

        if ($this->Pages->save($page))
        {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your page has been created.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }

        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your page.'));
    }

    $this->set('page', $page);
}

/**
 * Edit method
 *
 * @param string|null $id Page id.
 * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
 * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $page = $this->Pages->get($id);

    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put']))
    {
        $this->Pages->patchEntity($page, $this->request->getData());

        if(!$page->getErrors()) {
            $oldImage = $page->image;
            $image = $this->request->getData('image_file');
            $filename = $image->getClientFilename();
            $filename = \Cake\Utility\Security::hash($image->getClientFilename(), 'sha1');

            $image->moveTo(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'pages' . DS . $filename);
            $page->image = $filename;

            unlink(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'pages' . DS . $oldImage);
        }

        if ($this->Pages->save($page))
        {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your page has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }

        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your page.'));
    }

    $this->set('page', $page);
}

/**
 * Delete method
 *
 * @param string|null $id Page id.
 * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects to index.
 * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
 */
public function delete($id)
{
    $page = $this->Pages->get($id);

    if ($this->Pages->delete($page))
    {
        unlink(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'pages' . DS . $page->image);
        $this->Flash->success(__('The {0} page has been deleted.', $page->title));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you actually _want_ this "_share images between pages_" behavior?

Comment: Not really, I want one image assigned per page, even if the image could be the same for some pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually want this "*share images between pages*" behavior, then you need to come up with a different naming/storage scheme. For example you could use UUIDs, chances for duplicates are very very very tiny (assuming the pseudo-random number generator used by PHP is any good).

On top of that, put a unique index on the database column that holds the filename, and upload the file only after the record has been saved successfully, this helps avoiding the race condition problems from PHP level.

Of course it also never hurts to implement some kind of duplicate check strategy in order to minimize the chance of your code trying to store duplicates in the first place, eg check if the name already exists, and error out in that case, and possibly try to generate a unique name multiple times first. To reduce the possibility of clashes even more, you could use subfolders with names that change over time, for example use year and month.

Quick and dirty example:

```php
// group by year and month
$base = WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'pages' . DS;
$group = gmdate('Y-m') . DS;

$image = $this->request->getData('image_file');

// try to generate unique filename max 10 times
$uniqueFilenameFound = false;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    $filename = \Cake\Utility\Text::uuid();
    if (!file_exists($base . $group . $filename)) {
        $uniqueFilenameFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

// set field if unique name was found, otherwise set an error
if ($uniqueFilenameFound) {
    $page->image = $group . $filename;
} else {
    $page->setError('image_file', 'Could not generate a unique filename.');
}

// ...

// move file only after successful saving that ensures the name
// is really unique
if ($this->Pages->save($page))
{
    $image->moveTo($base . $group . $filename);
    
    // ...
}
```

All that being said, you should also consider moving this functionality into a service, a [**behavior**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/behaviors.html), or possibly the table itself. Handling the upload in [**the `afterSave` event**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/table-objects.html#aftersave) would allow for automatic rollbacks in case moving the file fails (this will trigger an exception)!